# Node.js with express : How to wait until all element loaded (including one with ajax request or angular.js)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax, node.js

I'm trying to scrape one page that loaded completely after a while. I use `request.get` and the request returned `response.statusCode == 200`.

The only problem is, the page is still loading and requesting something with `ajax` request. My best guess from the page is they are using `angular.js` so it's SPA.

> ISSUE : I want to scrape all `div` in the products site, the one that is not yet loaded.

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

var app = express();

app.get('/scrape', function(req, res){
    var options = {
      url: 'http://example.com'
    };

    request.get(options, function(error, response, html){
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {

            var $ = cheerio.load(html);

            if(!error){
                var i=0;

                console.log(html); // here (in the html variable) I found the page is still loaded with {width.something etc} << my best guess is this one is angular.js code
            }
        }
    });
});

app.listen('8081');
console.log('Listening...'); 
exports = module.exports = app;
```

how can I use `request` to wait until all request including ajax or `angular.js` request to finish? I've tried many things including `waitUntilExist` function but still no luck

Comment: You can use modules like nightmare.js / phantom.js for scraping websites. It will allow you to wait till some ajax calls are finished.

Comment: Wow, quick answer. Thanks. Will try on it. Sorry I'm node.js newbie, just a basic question, is it ok to use node with phantom.js or nightmare.js? Is it natively used? Or commonly used?

Comment: yes. both are available as node modules.

Comment: Instead of loading the whole page I'd try to figure out what's the ajax call and request it directly from the node script.

Comment: It's really hard because the site is so big so the file management and so on is very complicated. Do you have any "easy" way to track the request?